# javascript recursive function with arrays only processes firs leg

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

This seems like a basic and trivial question, but I cannot figure out why some of the inner loop doesn't get processed. I have an array of objects. I call the function with the name variable inside the object and then find the index of the object in the array. If the object has children, I then process all the children by recursively calling the function with the name of each child. This goes on until the object does not have children.

The result is that it drills all the way down on only the first child of the initial object (it has seven in my examples) and does not process the other six. In that first one it completes all the way to the end (the bottom layer has eight children and they are all processed.

```
    function modifyCheckBox(thisName, itemChecked) {
        if (!itemChecked) itemChecked = 
            document.getElementById(thisName).checked;
            //find the position in the array for thie object
            var inputIndex = getIndex(thisName, checkBoxArray);
            alert("Processing "+thisName+" with inputIndex of "+inputIndex);
            if (checkBoxArray[inputIndex].hasChildren) {
                childArray = getChildren(checkBoxArray[inputIndex].name);
                childArrayString = "";
                for (k=0; k<childArray.length; k++) {
                    childArrayString += childArray[k].name + "  ";
                }
                alert ("Processing children " + childArrayString + " of " +
                    checkBoxArray[inputIndex].name + " with inputIndex=" + 
                    inputIndex);
                for (j=0; j<childArray.length; j++) {
                    //Repeat the process for this child
                    modifyCheckBox(childArray[j].name, itemChecked);
                }
                alert("Completed children of " + 
                      checkBoxArray[inputIndex].name);
            } else {
                alert(checkBoxArray[inputIndex].name + " has no children");
            }
       }
```

The output list of alerts is

```
    Processing chk_AINF with inputIndex of 5
    Processing children chk_TRK  chk_LEL  chk_FAST  chk_RW  chk_ARSRV  
                chk_SIG  chk_AMW of chk_AINF with inputIndex=5
        Processing chk_TRK with inputIndex of 6
            Processing children chk_TRK_0  chk_TRK_1  chk_TRK_2  chk_TRK_3  
                    chk_TRK_4 chk_TRK_5    chk_TRK_6  chk_TRK_7  of chk_TRK 
                    with  inputIndex=6
                Processing chk_TRK_0 with inputIndex of 50
                chk_TRK_0 has no children
                .......
                chk_TRK_7 has no children
            Completed children of chk_TRK
   Completed children of chk_AINF
```

The question I have is what happened to chk_LEL  chk_FAST  chk_RW  chk_ARSRV  chk_SIG and  chk_AMW, the rest of the topmost children?

Comment: I wonder if it's treating some of your local variables as globals (since you aren't declaring them with `var`) - so that when modifyCheckbox runs on a child it's changing the loop counters for the parent.  I would try declaring childArray, childArrayString, j and k using the var keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right way to use recursion:

```
           for (j=0; j<childArray.length; j++) {
                //Repeat the process for this child
                modifyCheckBox(childArray[j].name, itemChecked);
            }
```

You keep re-initializing `j` to zero, so it's only going to look at that first branch.  Try intializing `j` (using the `var` keyword) outside of the function, then increment it inside the function.  Then you can recurse as you see fit until your child elements are exhausted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.what you are saying here. However, what did was to change that for loop to  be   childArray.forEach(function(child){
            modifyCheckBox(child.name, itemChecked);
        });

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying here, jmargolisvt . However, what did to make it work was to change that for loop to:

```
    childArray.forEach(function(child){
        modifyCheckBox(child.name, itemChecked);
    });
```

**Thank you for pointing out where the problem was.**

I had deleted it because I thought after posting that it still didn't work.  It did work. (I found other problems that made it seem as if it didn't work.) This, I believe, is the simplest solution.